# How stop the other videos when current is playing ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have a web application with diffrent videos (Youtube + DailyMotion)

I have been looking for hours on how to stop a Youtube iframe video, or stoping other youtube DailyMotion videos when current is playing.

Or how to enable only fullscreen video. I want just to avoid playing more that 1 video in the same time.

Comment: As an FYI not even Facebook has managed to fix this, good luck with it mate :(

Comment: You should render video player programatically in order to control it later. Youtube API has stopVideo() method: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: give an example please

Comment: @YassMoz here working example: http://jsfiddle.net/34hysaes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know video id's you can render video player programatically:

Load youtube API and define placeholder (#playList)

```
<script src='//www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>
<div id='playList'>
    <!--// placeholder -->
</div>
```

On page load:

```
var playList = [
    { videoId: 'aEHIgjoueeg', player: null, $el: null },
    { videoId: 'c5NcaVp2-5M', player: null, $el: null },
    { videoId: 'IA88AS6Wy_4', player: null, $el: null }
];
function onStateChange (e) {
    if (YT.PlayerState.PLAYING === e.data) {
        console.log(this, e);
        // stop others
        $.each(playList, function (i, item) {
            if (item.videoId === this.videoId) {
                return true;
            }
            if (item.player) {
                item.player.stopVideo();
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
var $playList = $('#playList');
$.each(playList, function (i, item) {
    item.$el = $('<div id="'+ item.videoId +'"></div>');
    $playList.append(item.$el);
    item.player = new window.YT.Player(item.videoId, {
        width: 300, height: 200,
        videoId: item.videoId,
        playerVars: { autoplay: 0 },
        events: {
            onStateChange: onStateChange.bind(item)
        }
    });
});
```

Inside onStateChange: if current video is playing then stop others
http://jsfiddle.net/34hysaes/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make code which interacts with specific APIs for youtube and dailymotion, but you could just use JS to replace the iframe node or its source property. This means that videos won't keep loading in the background too, in case this was for alternative sources of the same video.

http://jsfiddle.net/wesakm78/

```js
function selectVideo(e) {
    document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = e.target.getAttribute("data-source");
}

document.getElementById("youtubeButton").addEventListener("click", selectVideo);
document.getElementById("dailyButton").addEventListener("click", selectVideo);
```

```html
<button id="youtubeButton" data-source="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ">YouTube</button>
<button id="dailyButton" data-source="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xsdji">Dailymotion</button>

<iframe id="videoFrame" width="480" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: (videos may not work due to the way fiddles and snippets do or don't allow frames to prevent XSS, I'm not a pro on that subject)

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea that works, but seems pretty flakey on many browsers. Use at your own risk, since I find on my chromium (but not chrome) my cursor disappears when I enter the window.

The basic idea is to track the events we do have access to in our DOM - in this case, I'm just tracking mouseover, but you might want to check some others too. When you mouseover one video, it goes through the others, dups their iframe node, removes the original and replaces it. This essentially 'stops' the video by removing it and adding it back in. If you add some smarter logic, you could make it only do this to videos that might be playing (ie the ones you've moused/tapped into already).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var windows = [];
  var getVids = function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll('.youtube');
  };
  var vids = getVids();

  [].forEach.call(vids, function(video) {
    // Build window list of iframes
    video.addEventListener('mouseover', function(ev) {
      [].forEach.call(vids, function(othervid) {
        if (othervid !== video) {
          var newvid = othervid.cloneNode(true);
          var parent = othervid.parentNode;
          parent.insertBefore(newvid, othervid);
          parent.removeChild(othervid);
          // Reset to new vid list
          vids = getVids();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I realize this will need a bit of work to operate smoothly in your implementation, but hopefully this concept is enough to get you started.